# The history of equation tags

Tags: tex-history, tag

In plain TeX, one can add tags to equations by using `\eqno` and `\leqno`. Since the development of `amsmath` package, we can now use `\tag` and `\tag*` to assign tags to equations. So, in the period when `amsmath` had not come out, did TeX users have any other ways to set tags except using `\eqno` and `\leqno`?

Comment: Plain TeX by D. Knuth (1980), AMSTeX by M. Spivak (1982), LaTeX first released by L. Lamport (1984). It seems that AMSTeX was earlier than LaTeX. The features from AMSTeX (as a separate macro for PlainTeX or a separated generated format) was re-implemented to a LaTeX package sometime around 1992. There was an "intermediate" format called AMSLaTeX in these days too.

Comment: `\tag`  (if used in display math) expands to (amongst other things) `\eqno`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from some niche formats, before 1992 there was the choice between bare plain TeX, AMS-TeX and LaTeX.

For mathematical writing, AMS-TeX (with its wonderful manual by Mike Spivak) was essentially the only choice. LaTeX provided for automatic numbering and cross-references, but only offered `\newtheorem`, `equation` and `eqnarray` (the latter producing plainly wrong output). People using LaTeX for mathematics often resorted to plain TeX constructs, but these didn't support numbering: not the best framework.

To the contrary, AMS-TeX provided no automatic numbering nor cross-references, but had very flexible mechanisms to typeset theorem-like structures in different styles or alignment displays, to which it wasn't difficult to add tags. I only used AMS-TeX since when I could obtain the AMS fonts for the Macintosh (they came in floppy disks), about 1987, iirc. I knew about LaTeX and tried my hand on it, but it was definitely unsuited for mathematical papers (in my field, at least).

Around 1993 I started to study LaTeX because of the New Font Selection Scheme by Mittelbach and Schöpf that provided support for AMS fonts and so made it possible to port AMS-TeX under the name of `amslatex`; in order to practice, I produced my lecture notes for a new course using `amslatex`.

In the meantime I was helping my former advisor in the typesetting of his book (the basic typescript had already been produced in AMS-TeX by someone else) and implemented myself cross-references and automatic numbering.

In 1994 a colleague of mine asked help for typesetting a mathematical physics conference proceedings book, quite a tough task because the papers had *very* complex and long equations and alignments.

With the release of LaTeX2e that incorporated NFSS2 and sported `amsmath` the situation improved considerably; the transition was not painless: changing `amslatex` into `amsmath` didn't produce many errors, but several constructs of the former didn't really work with the latter yielding funny output. But once I understood what had to be changed (the `@`-shorthands, mostly), it was easy to fix the typescript.