# Newer versions of LaTeX fail to ignore spaces after display math environments which end with two dollar signs ($$) and contain \eqno

Tags: math-mode

The LaTeX file

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
$$ a \eqno 1 $$
N\\N

$$ a \eqno 1 $$%
N\\N
\end{document}
```

produces an unwanted space after the first displayed equation under "LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1":

[image]

Under previous versions of LaTeX such as "LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1", the file produced

[image]

I tried to obtain the previous behavior by inserting

```
\setcounter{localmathalphabets}{0}
```

before the `\begin{document}` command, following the suggestion in [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649690/weird-small-indentation-after-formula?noredirect=1#649694), but that did not change the output.  I also tried to obtain the previous behavior by inserting

```
\RequirePackage[2021/11/15]{latexrelease}
```

before the `\begin{document}` command, but that did not change the output either.  What can I do so that old documents produce the same output as they did before?

(If one removes `\eqno` then the unwanted space disappears.)

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  It's recommended that `$$` not be used with LaTeX; `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` is recommended instead, and equation numbers are provided automatically.  (There's also the problem with `$$` that, if the equation is very long, an equation number is overprinted.  I don't know any automatic fix for that; it isn't a problem with `equation`.)

Comment: ``\RequirePackage[2021-06-01]{latexrelease}`` before `\documentclass` as a provisory measure.

Comment: I can confirm that the suggestion by @user691586 works.

Comment: It turns out that `\RequirePackage[2021-11-14]{latexrelease}` also works.

Comment: This is so screwed up.  Easily a third or more of LaTeX documents use $$, if not more.  Many of them, such as arXiv papers, simply cannot be changed.  Are they all going to have wrong formatting from now on?  arXiv is known to periodically upgrade and recompile LaTeX documents, which means this regression will now propagate into older papers that used to have correct formatting.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov a third of latex documents use `\eqno` , really??     in any case https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1059

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Probably less than a third of LaTeX documents use \eqno, but a lot of them _do_ use \eqno, including many papers on arXiv that cannot be fixed.  Thank you for filing the bug report, I hope this regression gets fixed.

Comment: i'll have a search I don't think I have _ever_ seen `\eqno` in a latex document in over 30 years supporting latex, but as I say we'll  probably fix it

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: A fix would help with documents written by authors using robust workarounds forged in the difficult "before 1992" era [described](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664652/the-history-of-equation-tags) by egreg: "For mathematical writing, AMS-TeX... was essentially the only choice. LaTeX provided for automatic numbering and cross-references, but only offered... eqnarray (the latter producing plainly wrong output). People using LaTeX for mathematics often resorted to plain TeX constructs... AMS-TeX provided no automatic numbering nor cross-references."

Comment: @GabrielA.Lozada sure but that is rather less than a third of the entire latex corpus-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I'll defer to you on that!

Comment: This small formatting problem with old documents is probably a (very) small price to pay, and it may finally make people to change to proper latex syntax.

Comment: @MátéWierdl: Price to pay for _what_, exactly?  There is no benefit compared to the situation when this bug is fixed.

Comment: @DmitriPavolv People finally writing proper latex documents instead of passing down incorrect syntax for generations. Because of this practice, I still see graduate students who do not know that latex can automatically number equations which then can be referenced via labels. These students never ever open a latex reference since "all compiles fine".  Only later they may see that when they send their files to collaborators, the collaborators may have a hard time with corrections and additions.

Comment: @MátéWierdl: But it's not incorrect syntax; “incorrect syntax” has a precise meaning: the compiler must give an error or a diagnostic message, and LaTeX processes $$...$$ and \eqno just fine without any warnings whatsoever.  By the way, it is trivial to automatically number equations using $$...$$ and \eqno, and in fact that's what some of us use (e.g., with a macro).  It produces a far more readable source code than the clumsy \begin{equation}...\end{equation}, especially if you use lots of displayed formulas.  In addition, $$...$$ does not have the infamous spacing bug present in \\[...\\].

Comment: @MátéWierdl: I mentioned in my first comment on David Carlislie's answer that I, just like Dmitri Pavlov, use macros to automatically number equations using $$...$$ and `\eqno`.  Indeed it is because I wanted to automatically number _complicated_ equation numbers that I originally used $$...$$ and `\eqno`.  (Well that and to avoid the awful `\eqnarray`.)

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: What is the "infamous spacing bug present in `\[...\]`"?  Is it the [displayshortskip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385774/amsmath-redefine-align-to-support-abovedisplayshortskip-and-belowdisplayshor) problem? I can confirm that, as Barbara Beeton [observed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541867/why-is-a-second-displaymath-instance-a-short-line), the Plain TeX equation alignment commands (which I've been using) don't have that problem.  Until this is fixed in amsmath, Plain's $$...$$ constructs seem superior to LaTeX's (given automatic numbering macros).

Comment: @GabrielA.Lozada: The spacing bug is described in detail here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to/163205#163205

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: Thanks!  That problem is inconsistent spacing between displayed equations denoted by \[...\] and immediately following each other and beginning a paragraph.  It could be fixed by using amsmath's "gather."  The displayshortskip problem I referenced above is different and harder to fix, although wea0 proposed a solution there (revised by Bolpat).

Comment: (To use Plain's $$...$$ multi-equation constructs in LaTeX, one would have to copy Plain's definitions for `\eqalign`, `\eqalignno`, `\leqalignno`, and `\displaylines`; see for example the cjwplain package.)

Comment: The bug has been fixed in the git repository of LaTeX: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/cb79452f43b76a3248a9d4a2128a435f3952fb88

Comment: The problem has been fixed in the LaTeX release of 2023-06-01, as documented on page 5 of the corresponding issue of [LaTeX News](https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews37.pdf).  Thanks to @DavidCarlisle for his willingness to fixing the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$$` has never been supported latex syntax, so this should never have appeared in a latex document, but you could do:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\let\xxeqno\eqno
\def\eqno{\xxeqno\aftergroup\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}
$$ a \eqno 1 $$
N\\N

$$ a \eqno 1 $$%
N\\N
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works, so I can process legacy documents without much change, which is great!  For equation numbers on the left, one would use, e.g., `\let\yyleqno\leqno
\def\leqno{\yyleqno\aftergroup\ignorespaces}`.  As for $$ "should never have appeared in a LaTeX document," my excuse is that in 1989 when I wrote macros to automatically number equations such as (7'), (A1), (A2), (A1'), (A3a), (A3b), I could not figure out how to do it using then-existing LaTeX constructs, so I used Plain TeX constructs.  For more than 30 years those macros didn't break so I didn't fix them.

Comment: There are tons and tons of LaTeX documents out there that use $$.  Is it really reasonable to suggest that they all be edited to change $$ to \\[ or add percent signs after $$?  What about documents that cannot be changed, such as arXiv papers etc.?  Are there any plans to fix this regression in a future version of LaTeX?

Comment: @DmitriPavlov oh we will probably fix it but it is important to stress that `$$` has never been supported syntax it is not even mentioned in the latex 
 book. also note here `$$` is not the problem it is `\eqno` I have hardly ever seen eqno used in a latex document

Comment: @DmitriPavlov  The problem presents itself only when `\eqno` is used together with `$$`.  This combination is surely not in "tons and tons" of documents, and those people who are outraged  by this tiny formatting change  potentially appearing in their old documents will indeed be very small,and they can safely be asked to add those two corrective lines to their outdated and incorrectly written documents.

Comment: @MátéWierdl: In many contexts, it is not possible to “add corrective lines”.  For example, papers on arXiv cannot be changed, and although new versions can be uploaded, in many cases it is impractical (e.g., if the author died).  This is not a “tiny formatting change”: it can change page numbers, potentially rendering existing references to arXiv papers invalid.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov there are some, eg https://arxiv.org/format/1801.08138 but  you have to search quite hard, your suggestion that it is a third of all documents is rather unreasonable:-) however it's a pointless discussion since (a) I show the fix here and (b) at no point did I suggest a similar fix wouldn't be added to latex.

Comment: Hm, so latex developers are at a crossroads: should they let people continue to write incorrect latex documents or from now on people will start using proper latex facilities instead of mixing in TeX.  The change from latex 2.09 to latex 2e was much more dramatic, but people adjusted, because they saw the fantastic benefits.     As @GabrielALozada wrote, if things don't work, people will fix incorrect syntax---but only then.

Comment: @MátéWierdl if it gave an error, perhaps, but not silently adding bad space. Are you offering to check a couple of million arxiv files and update as needed? The change to 2e was not that dramatic, if you kept `\documentstyle` the vast majority of documents ran unchanged

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It certainly gets hopelessly  confusing that one gets an error about bad usage in case  `\[ a  \eqno 1 \] N\\ N` but not when `$$ a \eqno 1 $$ N\\ N`.  And the error message disappears when I add `\usepackage{amsmath}`.

Comment: David Carlisle discusses in the [git repository](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1059) how the LaTeX project team could address the conflict that this fix can have with amsmath.