# How to make a new command that accepts math parameters?

Tags: math-mode, renewcommand, text-mode, robust-commands

So I have been trying to make a command to display my very particular notation for restriction, but I believe parts of it involve text commands and other parts involve math commands, I thought I had properly considered each but I still get errors about the parameters not being in math mode:

The command:

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphics}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rest}[1]{\text{\raisebox{-5.8pt}{\scalebox{1}[2.6]{$\upharpoonright$}_{\ensuremath{#1}}}\hspace{-7pt}}}
```

Would work but I still get error messages about lacking the $ $ in the arguments (even if I do put them in there).

The result that I wanted to get from this command was to be the same as if I wrote:

```
$$\pi\raisebox{-5.8pt}{\scalebox{1}[2.6]{$\upharpoonright$}}_{H}\hspace{-7pt}(a)$$
```

when i write

```
$$\pi\rest{H}(a)$$
```

And that should look like:

[image]

Comment: May I ask: what is the reason for using `\text` in that definition of `\rest`?

Comment: `\scalebox{1}[2.6]{$\upharpoonright$}_{`   has `_`in  text, the whole of scalebox shoud be in `$...$` and do not use `\enuremath` here

Comment: @daleif I believe that those box (\scalebox,,\raisebox) commands are for text enviroments, I may be wrong but that would explain why I need to put the $...$ inside \scalebox for it to work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you mean \ensuremath ?

Comment: sorry yes, once you have fixed the `$` you will be in math so no need to use `\ensuremath` to test for math. Note also you should not use `$$` in latex

Comment: "but that would explain why I need to put the $...$ inside \scalebox for it to work." no you _always_ need `$` in `\scalebox` not just in `\text`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't really wanna argue here about this, but is there really a concrete reason why I should use \\[ \\] instead of $$ $$ beyond "its (supossedly) deprecated"?

Comment: It is not "deprecated" that would imply it was once supported but now not, but `$$` has never been documented as latex syntax,  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to/69854#69854  or more recently https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/684210/1090

Comment: It is a part of TeX though, and for unumbered equations it has a very nice complementary sintax relation with $...$, these types of dicussions seem like those in which someone considers a sin to code in C++ like C, if it works, and doesn't break anything, I don't see the probem.

Comment: @FelipeDilho It *does* break things.

Comment: `\scalebox` and `\raisebox` can be used everywhere, it is just that it always typesets its argument as text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use no explicit dimensions, so the command can work at different sizes and different fonts.

I also add a `*`-version that copes with the problem of a “deep” function argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\NewDocumentCommand{\rest}{sm}{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{1}[2.6]{$\upharpoonright$}}}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    _{\!#2}%
  }{%
    _{\mathrlap{\!#2}}\,%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\pi\rest{H}(a)
\qquad
\pi\rest*{H}\biggl(\,\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\biggr)
\]

\end{document}
```

Explanation: `\vcenter` will center the object with respect to the formula axis. With `\mathrlap` the subscript is considered to have zero width, but that doesn't happen with `\rest*`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You do not need any `$` at all in the command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphics}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\rest}[1]{\raisebox{-5.8pt}{\scalebox{1}[2.6]{$\upharpoonright$}}_{#1}\hspace{-7pt}}

\begin{document}
    $\pi\raisebox{-5.8pt}{\scalebox{1}[2.6]{$\upharpoonright$}}_{H}\hspace{-7pt}(a)$
    
    $\pi\rest{H}(a)$
    
\end{document}
```

I also removed the `\pi` and `(a)`  from the command since it seems you want them completely variable and put them before and after the commmand when you use it by your example in the question.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! So only the parameter of \scalebox must contain the $...$, huh, functionally would that mean that \scalebox: \elementoftextmode -> \elementofmathmode ?

Comment: Basicly the content of your command is placed instead of its name in the text. You already put `$$` on the outside. If you put `$` again you are going out of maths mode and therefore they are missing and you get the error message you had been getting.