Extraneous indentation on the line following double-dollar display math with \eqno or \leqno
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  $$x\eqno (1)$$
  N\\N
  $$y\leqno (2)$$
  N\\N
\end{document}


The lines following display equations $$...$$ with \eqno or \leqno are slightly indented. Looks like this is a known bug: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1059
Is there any workaround or alternative?

Don't use $$...$$ in latex - Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$?

Update your TeX distribution? It is fixed in current LaTeX.

@cfr, my TeX distribution is installed as a system package.

Well, you have to install upstream or persuade your distro to patch/update or wait. Theoretically, I guess you could try to do something local, but that sounds as if it would be messy (judging from the bug discussion). As @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz says, this isn't LaTeX syntax anyway, so the real solution is not to use $$ in LaTeX.

see https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1059

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, with \[...\], can I choose which equations to center and which to flush left (fleqn), and in which to put the tag on the left and in which on the right?

duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684207/newer-versions-of-latex-fail-to-ignore-spaces-after-display-math-environments-wh

@user691586, indeed, but i did not find that question despite searching.

The fix was applied at LaTeX 2023-06-01

You're asking for an alternative.
First off, equation numbers should be either all on the right or all on the left. In LaTeX you use equation and not $$. This way, the equation number is automatically provided and you don't need to take care of them manually.
In the following examples, I use twocolumn just for making smaller pictures.
No option, numbers on the right
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
x
\end{equation}
text that wraps over to the next line,
showing that no indentation appears
\begin{equation}
y
\end{equation}
text that wraps over to the next line,
showing that no indentation appears

\end{document}


With leqno numbers are on the left
\documentclass[leqno,twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
x
\end{equation}
text that wraps over to the next line,
showing that no indentation appears
\begin{equation}
y
\end{equation}
text that wraps over to the next line,
showing that no indentation appears

\end{document}


With fleqn equations are at a fixed distance from the margin
\documentclass[fleqn,twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
x
\end{equation}
text that wraps over to the next line,
showing that no indentation appears
\begin{equation}
y
\end{equation}
text that wraps over to the next line,
showing that no indentation appears

\end{document}


You can also get numbers on the left by adding the leqno option.

Comments
You see that the document code doesn't change, only the options.
Workaround
If you insist in using the deprecated $$ and manually providing equation numbers, with all the problems this creates, you can do what the current LaTeX kernel does.
\documentclass[fleqn,leqno,twocolumn]{article}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{@kernel@eqno}{%
  \let\@kernel@eqno\eqno
  \let\@kernel@leqno\leqno
  \protected\def\eqno{\@kernel@eqno\aftergroup\ignorespaces}%
  \protected\def\leqno{\@kernel@leqno\aftergroup\ignorespaces}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$$
x\eqno(1)
$$
text that wraps over to the next line,
showing that no indentation appears
$$
y\leqno(1)
$$
text that wraps over to the next line,
showing that no indentation appears

\end{document}


Tested with TeX Live from 2012 to 2024.

"First off, equation numbers should be either all on the right or all on the left" -- it depends. I may want to show examples of different styles in the same document, or (as is my case) quote various sources while trying to keep their style and layout.

@Alexey Look at nccmath that provides environments for switching the position of equation numbers mid document. If you want manual numbering, there's \tag from amsmath. You have to work harder to find an argument that will convince me that $$ has any place inside a LaTeX document environment (it can be used for defining environments, though).

Thanks, I'll check out nccmath. I was not saying that $$ "had a place". I was using it as a quick solution. Of course ideally LaTeX should function like a modern programming language, where you can do anything locally without messing up the whole.

I think the fix as applied to LaTeX kernel was
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\@kernel@eqno\eqno
\let\@kernel@leqno\leqno
\protected\def\eqno{\@kernel@eqno\aftergroup\ignorespaces}
\protected\def\leqno{\@kernel@leqno\aftergroup\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  $$x\eqno (1)$$
  N\\N
  $$y\leqno (2)$$
  N\\N
\end{document}

But don't do that with LaTeX 2023-06-01 or later as it creates infinite loop.
